# Create & Show images as background-image one by one - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image, css-transforms

**Problem statement** - I need to create & show multiple images dynamically from my directory one by one, with transform - scale ( for showing ) applied to it. But my code is showing them together at once.

HTML:

```
<div class="images-cont">       
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 160px;
    transform: scale(0,0); 
    transition: all 4s;
    background:no-repeat center center;
    display:inline-block;
}
a.scale{ transform: scale(1,1);}
```

JS:

```
$("document").ready(function(){ 
    var minImages = 1;   // Images are numbered from 1.jpg till 10.jpg
    var maxImages = 10; 


    for(i=1;i<=maxImages;i++){
        buildImageLink();
    }

    showImages();

    function buildImageLink(){
        var anchor = $(document.createElement('a'));
        anchor.attr('href','#').appendTo('.images-cont');
        loadImage(anchor);
    };

    function loadImage(elem){
        var f = new Image;
        var p = 'images/' + i + '.jpg';  // Location of the images directory 
        f.src = p;
        f.addEventListener("load", function() {
            elem.css({ 'background-image': 'url('+ p +')'});            
        });     
    };

    function showImages(){
        $('.images-cont a').each(function(){
            $(this).delay(1000).addClass('scale')
        })
    }
});
```

Have gone through a number of posts in SO itself, and refined my code accordingly, but its still the same. I am not understanding what I am missing here. The delay is just not happening.

Comment: where exactly, can you please explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.delay()` does not apply to `.addClass()`, only to animation queues

What you want is probably a **setTimeout** function:

```
function showImages(){
    $('.images-cont a').each(function(i, el){ // `i` is Index, `el` is HTMLElement object
        setTimeout(function(){
             $(el).addClass('scale');
        }, i * 1000); // (0*1000=0; 1*1000=1000, 2*1000=2000 etc)
    })
}
```

---

Also, instead of `var anchor = $(document.createElement('a'));` you can do:

```
var anchor = $("<a />");
```

or even:

```
var anchor = $("<a />", {href:"#"});
/* and than just: */ anchor.appendTo('.images-cont');
```

---

Also it's suggested to change the order:

```
    f.addEventListener("load", function() {
        elem.css({ 'background-image': 'url('+ p +')'});            
    });  
    f.src = p; // After instantiating the load function
```

Comment: Would you please recommend any other alternative, in order to achieve this?

Comment: @whyAto8 sure, I was editing my answer to make it shine a bit

Comment: Fantastic, that works. Thank you so much. And about the var anchor = $("<a />"); , just confirming, is it faster than what I used i.e. document.createElement, I have been using this, as I checked this at a lot of SO's discussion that its faster for creating elements.

Comment: @whyAto8 You're welcome! P.S. sorry, which one is faster? You're confusing me

Comment: Isnt var anchor = $(document.createElement('a')); faster than var anchor = $("<a />"); ?

Comment: @whyAto8 I never did a benchmark with that one... Probably it is (since a native JS method is used...) But should that 0.000001 ms extra time fall in favor of the coolness of using `$("<a/>",{href:"#"})`? I'll do a benchmark. brb

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I agree :-) , thanks for helping out on this.

Comment: @whyAto8 http://jsperf.com/jq-js-mix-create-element/ - jQ wins in your specific case.